# How to make efficient PhD research in absence of the supervisor?

Tags: phd, thesis

I am a PhD student, in my situation I work totally alone and freely , the good thing here is that I have learned to be autonomic and I can guide my research by my own, however, In comparison with the other Phd student , I don’t have a guide or even a corrector that I can discuss my work with; so that; as a solution I feel more comfortable when I write,  still less experienced, but when I write I read and I learn more and more, for the moment, writing replaces the absence of my supervisor!!!
Working alone is not so dramatic; I try to extract the maximum of positivity facing the challenge of doing a PhD almost alone, I shared my experience because I’m curious; what can we learn from that? are there student in the same situation? If not; what would you do in such a case?

Comment: Why is your supervisor absent?

Comment: *And no, I don't think flagging this as a duplicate of another thread from today would be appropriate. If nothing else, it'd be very poor taste.*

Comment: yes, in fact, he is almost absent he supervise a lot of students that i found myself really working alone almost in the half of my way

Comment: If your question is about your supervisor who is not allocating sufficient time to you as his PhD student, I think that this question is asked before on this website: [How to deal with advisor not allocating time to me?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7493/how-to-deal-with-advisor-not-allocating-time-to-me)

Comment: Is your question more like, "Are there any disadvantages to not working closely with my supervisor?"

Comment: @Compass Why is it in poor taste to close as a duplicate of another question posted on the same day? If it's a duplicate, it's a duplicate, regardless of whether the other question was posted five minutes ago or five years ago: there's no benefit to the site in having the same question here twice. In fact, there's harm, as it fragments answers and wastes people's time when they write something that's already been covered by somebody else.

Comment: @DavidRicherby because unlike the other question which involved the advisor's *passing*, this one does not involve an advisor being gone at all.

Comment: I still think it is a diffrent case; besides i have talked to him but he ignores what i say he just pretend like every thing is ok, and each time i face him with the work that i did as a parameter to discuss my work, he always find an excuse pretending also that he has a work to do, i get really stuck in the middle of my path, lets say  it will be ok if i work alone but nobody will correct my thesis, and i just start to worry about how can i enhance my cv, i feel paralyzed and sad which doesn't represent me at all...                                                 thank you for your answers